# Restore standard horizontal spacing for colored symbols in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, color

I have to highlight some symbols in red, something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$2+2+2=6 \textcolor{red}{\to} 4+2=6$
\end{document}
```

However the colored formula horizontal spacing changes and the arrow almost touches the left and right symbols. To solve this I created a new command, like this:

```
\newcommand{\redto}{~\textcolor{red}{\to}~}
```

but this seems like a suboptimal solution to me. Is there a proper way to let colored symbols keep the standard horizontal spacing in mathmode?

Comment: yes, sorry for the dupe. Please close it.